# What happens if I never call stopListening() on firebaseUI recycler adapter

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

If I don't provide an activity to manage the lifecycle, and instead do it manually but never close the adapter by calling stopListening(), what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case the listener will remain active until the app is closed, or the socket is killed by the operating system. You'll be wasting your user's bandwidth and battery life, downloading data that they never see.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to figure out how how to launch an activity to enter new data or edit data that doesn't trigger a stop listening start listening cycle because that causes a refresh of the recycler view. That means the user loses their place in the list.